# How to extract content of attached mail in pst using apache TIKA

Tags: java, apache-tika

I want to extract the content of mail which is attached to another mail in PST using Apache TIKA. When i am parsing pst, the X-TIKA:content key of metadata for attached mail didnt have body of mail. How can i extract the body content of attached mail ? Here is the code:

```
public void parsePSTfile(File file) throws IOException, TikaException, org.xml.sax.SAXException 
{
    Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();
    RecursiveParserWrapper wrapper = new RecursiveParserWrapper(p,
            new BasicContentHandlerFactory(
                    BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.XML, -1));

    InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(file);
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    wrapper.parse(stream, new DefaultHandler(), new Metadata(), context);

    for (Metadata metadata : wrapper.getMetadata()) {

            for (String name : metadata.names()) {

                for (String value : metadata.getValues(name)) {
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Message-From"))
                        //set value in required object
                    if ("X-TIKA:content".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    //Here extracting the message body
                        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                        ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
                        Metadata xmetadata = new Metadata();
                        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        new HtmlParser().parse(inputStream,textHandler,xmetadata,new ParseContext());
                        //set value of textHandler.toString()in required object
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you calling Apache Tika? Java? If so, please post the code. Server or CLI? If so, please post the options / urls used.

Comment: Code has been added.

Comment: Why aren't you capturing the content received from your `ContentHandler`? See https://tika.apache.org/1.14/examples.html#Parsing_to_Plain_Text for examples